# Is it appropriate to use "to ignore" as a stative verb? (as a synonymous to "to be ignorant of")

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, word-usage

Suppose I ask you: 
"What is her name?" is the following answer ok?
"I cannot tell you, I ignore it" 
Or should I rather answer to in proper English:
" I cannot tell you, I am ignorant of it"

Does "to ignore" only have the following "non-stative" meaning: to fail to consider or to fail to pay attention?

Answer (score 1):

No,  *ignore* in English does not mean *not know*, but *deliberately take no notice of* something.

You *could* answer the question "What is her name?" with "I am ignorant of it", but it would sound very stilted and unnatural. A native speaker would say "I don't know it."

Answer (score 0):

Reading this reminded me of another way you could put it, if you are looking for a more artistic form.

You could answer, "What is her name?"  with something along the lines of, "If she has one, I am unaware of it."

So as to state a lack of knowledge of the name and an implied disregard for if she had or needed one to begin with.   :-)